# Finding the index of a specific SortedMap

Tags: scala, sortedmap

I have a `SortedMap` of the type:

`data: SortedMap[Long, SortedMap[String, Double]]`

How can I find the index of a specific key.

For example:

`data = (1L -> ("a" -> 1.), 2L -> ("b" -> 1., "c" -> 2.), 3L -> ("b" -> 1.))`

I want to find the index of key `2L` (the result should be `1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this approach based in an iterator over keys that avoids indexing intermediate collections as follows,

```
data.keysIterator.indexWhere(_ == 2)
```

For ease of use consider this implicit,

```
implicit class RichSortedMap[A,B](val m: SortedMap) extends AnyVal {
  def keyIndexWhere(k: A) = m.keysIterator.indexWhere( _ == k )
}
```

and so you can use it as follows,

```
data.keyIndexWhere(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zipWithIndex` to pair each key-value with it's index, then use `collectFirst` to find the pair with the correct key and extract the index. This will return `Option[Int]` (so `None` if the key is not found).

```
val data: SortedMap[Long, SortedMap[String, Double]] = SortedMap(
    1L -> SortedMap("a" -> 1.0), 
    2L -> SortedMap("b" -> 1.0, "c" -> 2.0), 
    3L -> SortedMap("b" -> 1.0)
)

def findIndex(data: SortedMap[Long, SortedMap[String, Double]], key: Long): Option[Int] = 
    data.zipWithIndex.collectFirst { case ((`key` , _), i) => i }

scala> findIndex(data, 1L)
res16: Option[Int] = Some(0)

scala> findIndex(data, 2L)
res17: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> findIndex(data, 10L)
res18: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: If performance is factor here, then using `data.view.zipWithIndex.collectFirst` would help you skip the intermediate collection creation.